# Unable to use 'gcloud alpha' command to create GKE with local SSDs using NVMe interface

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I am trying to create a GKE with a preconfigured local SSD configuration - namely I'd like for the devices to use the NVMe interface and do *not* format/mount the devices.

The `gcloud alpha container clusters create` command, as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/container/clusters/create), has a command line option called `--local-ssd-volumes` which supports these options.

A example is provided:

```
gcloud alpha container clusters create example_cluster --local-ssd-volumes count=2,type=nvme,format=fs

'count' must be between 1-8
'type' must be either scsi or nvme
'format' must be either fs or block
```

Whenever I try and use the `--local-ssd-volumes` option, I get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=404, message=Method not found.
```

While troubleshooting, I found a suggestion to use the GCP web console to generate most of the gcloud configuration. This has led me to using the following commandline:

```
$ gcloud alpha container --project "<REDACTED>" clusters create "gcp-ceph" \
  --zone "europe-west2-b" --no-enable-basic-auth \
  --cluster-version "1.20.8-gke.900" --release-channel "None" \
  --machine-type "n2-standard-2" --image-type "UBUNTU_CONTAINERD" \
  --disk-type "pd-standard" --disk-size "100" \
  --metadata disable-legacy-endpoints=true \
  --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append" \
  --max-pods-per-node "110" \
  --enable-kubernetes-alpha \
  --num-nodes "5" --enable-stackdriver-kubernetes \
  --enable-ip-alias --network "projects/<REDACTED>/global/networks/default" 
  --subnetwork "projects/<REDACTED>/regions/europe-west2/subnetworks/default" \
  --no-enable-intra-node-visibility --default-max-pods-per-node "110" \
  --no-enable-master-authorized-networks \
  --addons HorizontalPodAutoscaling,HttpLoadBalancing,GcePersistentDiskCsiDriver \
  --no-enable-autoupgrade --no-enable-autorepair \
  --max-surge-upgrade 1 --max-unavailable-upgrade 0 --enable-shielded-nodes \
  --node-locations "europe-west2-b" \
  --local-ssd-volumes "count=8,type=nvme,format=block"
```

The GCP console suggested I use `gcloud beta` when press `Equivalent COMMAND LINE`. When I run this, I get an expected error saying the command is not in Beta, but is found in alpha.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.container.clusters.create) unrecognized arguments:

 --local-ssd-volumes flag is available in one or more alternate release tracks. Try:

  gcloud alpha container clusters create --local-ssd-volumes
```

When I then use `gcloud alpha` I the the `404 Method Not Found` error.

How can I run this command? Do I need my project whitelisted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions, product is still in alpha and you might need to be whitelisted/invited. Check [notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/container/clusters/create) section at the bottom.

In [beta](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/container/clusters/create) I did not see the other options for local disk apart from the count, so I do not believe it will work with gcloud beta at this point.

Possible ways to get invited. Note this answer is more for the general community and does not guarantee success:

1. Depending on product a form might be made available, eg at [Google blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gke). This could happen with new products as an example.
2. Have access to an Account Manager at Google. Meaning you are currently working with Google.
3. Contact sales.
4. Post in [Google Discussion](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/groups) as those are monitored by Googlers but does not guarantee success of invite. Perhaps if you explain your business needs you might see some traction.

Answer (score 0):

Alpha APIs are only enabled on alpha clusters, and aren't meant for production use. Here are a few excerpts from the [relevant documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/alpha-clusters):

> To ensure stability and production quality, normal GKE clusters only enable features that are beta or higher. Alpha features are not enabled on normal clusters because they are not production-ready or upgradeable.

> Warning: Do not use Alpha clusters or alpha features for production workloads. Alpha clusters expire after thirty days and do not receive security updates. You must migrate your data from alpha clusters before they expire. GKE does not automatically save data stored on alpha clusters.

Comment: Where was production mentioned?